# Multiple useless CRLFs on pages

Tags: feature-request, optimization, bandwidth

Below is an example of how a typical Stack Exchange site page source looks like. That's [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100428/132564) but the results are more or less consistent across pages.

There're completely useless linefeeds circled. Now I don't say all linefeeds and whitespaces should be eliminated - that would hinder readability - but these extra linefeeds are just useless. Note that sometimes there're several linefeeds in row - that is believed to even reduce readability of the HTML.

Could you please get them removed at some point?

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:optimization] and [tag:bandwidth], but [your linked post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100428/why-dont-you-get-rid-of-your-newlines-and-spaces-minifi-your-pages) points out that compression means that the difference is only about 10%.  Are you arguing that this difference is significant, that this should be done to improve readability, or both?

Comment: I **DO NOT** think that about 10 lines of whitespace in the source will throw a fit with your ISP...

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer: Well... 1. these linefeeds are completely useless and 2. removing them can save some bandwidth and 3. removing them can improve readability. Looks like a win-win change yet not urgent of course. Btw 10% is for removing all the whitespaces and that's not a painless change and that's not what I suggest.

Comment: @sharptooth 1 is immaterial, 2 is also immaterial, and 3 is both immaterial and subjective. Looks like a meh-meh-meh change to me.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Why is saving bandwidth immaterial?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Because it results in no noticeable changes in page load times.  The time required to send those few blank lines over the wire is much less than time to send the rest of the page and much, much less than the overhead in making the requests and rendering the page.

Answer (score 9):

The sizes of [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100428/132564):

```
Formatting           | Uncompressed | Compressed (gzip)
---------------------+--------------+------------------
Current formatting   | 51340        | 12814
Removing blank lines | 50091        | 12647
```

That's a `2.4%` improvement when uncompressed and `1.3%` when compressed.

I'd hardly consider this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)...

Comment: That's small but worth it IMO.

Comment: Huh.  2.4% is higher than I expected it to be.  Certainly a micro-optimization, but perhaps it's not completely without merit?  (I mean, I've never worked on a very large-scale web application, so this is just speculation on my part)

Comment: I'm not saying that those blank lines **shouldn't** be removed, but I don't care and it's hardly a bug. Removing indentation, for example, would save much more bandwidth, especially when uncompressed. The lines *look* big, but whitespace consumes more bytes.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Many of the *empty* lines have actually spaces on them.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, gotcha.  FYI, I've retagged this as a feature-request.  That fits better than "bug" here.

Comment: Absolutely not worth developer time.

Comment: With [3.2M page views/day](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), that comes to ~13.5GB of bandwidth (assuming 150 bytes of savings per page load) wasted per month just for SO. Probably not worth fixing, although it would depending on how much SO pays for their bandwidth. Also, if bandwidth optimization is a priority, I suspect whitespace cleanup won't be the first thing on the hit list.